# Разница между collation Cyrillic_General и Cyrillic_General_100

Tags: sql-server, collation

Устанавливаю SQL Server 2016 Express Edition на Windows 2016 Server, хотел выбрать кириллическую collation, однако их находится две: Cyrillic_General и Cyrillic_General_100

[image: MS SQL Server 2016 cyrillic collations]

В чём между ними разница? Сомневаюсь в выборе. Вижу, что почти все сопоставления имеют два варианта (со _100 и без), что это значит и для чего нужно?

Comment: Ага, тоже интересно стало (хоть в винде я и не в зуб ногой, как говорится). Вот тут https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/windows-collation-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 пишут, что `_100` (еще упоминают `_90`) это Версия параметров сортировки. Я бы попробовал _100

Comment: @avp Эти циферки напоминают [уровень совместимости базы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2016), но только у меня в голове не умещается, что выбирается не SQL collaction, а Windows collation, в которой зашит SQL-уровень -- а вот в самой Windows нет никаких _100 -- и это как-то бредово.

Comment: AK, и не говорите, мне все эти варианты тоже не нравятся. Насколько всем программерам было бы проще сортировать прямо по кодам. (А пользуны бы в конце-концов привыкли -))

Comment: AK, судя по принятому ответу я угадал

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Cyrillic_General и Cyrillic_General_100
>   В чём между ними разница?

Насколько я исследовал этот вопрос, символы русского алфавита (*А-Я*, *а-я*), а также символы латинского алфавита, цифры и знаки (с кодами *0x0020-0x007E*) и в *Cyrillic_General* и в *Cyrillic_General_100* обрабатываются одинаково. Однако есть разница для кириллических символов не используемых в русском языке.

Например, в таблице символов Unicode первая в [кириллическом диапазоне](https://unicode-table.com/ru/blocks/cyrillic/) буква - *[Ѐ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%80_(%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0))* (е с грависом) в *Cyrillic_General_CI_AI* трактуется не равной букве *Ё*, а в *Cyrillic_General_100_CI_AI* буквы *Ѐ* и *Ё* равны (что, при игнорировании диакритических знаков, по-видимому, более правильно):

```
SELECT
    eq = IIF(ch1_ci_ai = ch2_ci_ai, '=', '<>'),
    eq_100 = IIF(ch1_100_ci_ai = ch2_100_ci_ai, '=', '<>')
FROM
    (VALUES (N'Ѐ', N'Ё')) c(ch1, ch2)
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            ch1_ci_ai = c.ch1 COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AI,
            ch2_ci_ai = c.ch2 COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AI,
            ch1_100_ci_ai = c.ch1 COLLATE Cyrillic_General_100_CI_AI,
            ch2_100_ci_ai = c.ch2 COLLATE Cyrillic_General_100_CI_AI
    ) c2
```

Также в *Cyrillic_General* буквы *Ѐ* и *ѐ* не преобразуются корректно к противоположному регистру, тогда как в *Cyrillic_General_100* преобразование регистра для них корректное:

```
SELECT
    le = LOWER(N'Ѐ' COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AI),
    ue = UPPER(N'ѐ' COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AI),
    le_100 = LOWER(N'Ѐ' COLLATE Cyrillic_General_100_CI_AI),
    ue_100 = UPPER(N'ѐ' COLLATE Cyrillic_General_100_CI_AI)
```

Есть разница и для некоторых других кириллических символов (и для не кириллических тоже).

> Сомневаюсь в выборе.

В общем случае для новых разработок лучше выбирать наиболее актуальные версии - это, как правило, те, что содержат *_100* в имени (для японского языка в SqlServer 2017 появились версии *_140*). Если же нужно обеспечить совместимость с какими-то уже существующими системами - выбирайте сообразно тому, что в них используется.

Обратите внимание также, что при установке задаётся *collation* инстанса. Для создаваемых в последствие баз данных всегда можно указать любой другой нужный *collation* (если не указать, то БД будет создана с *collation* инстанса). Поэтому, если вы не используете символы русского алфавита в названиях баз данных, логинов, серверных ролей и прочих instance-scope вещах, то, в принципе, можете выбрать даже и *Latin1_General_100*.

Answer (score 2):

Collation-ы _100 введены с версии MS SQL Server 2008. В общем случае лучше использовать новые, кроме какой-то специфики связанной с поддержкой "древних" приложений.

[What's New in SQL Server 2008 Collations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms143503(v=sql.105))

Основной пункт, на который я обратил бы внимание это:

> Weighting has been added to previously non-weighted characters that
>   would have compared equally.

Смысл в том, что ранее было достаточно много символов (как правило непечатных), для которых не был указан 'вес', поэтому при сравнении они рассматривались как одинаковые, хотя на самом деле были разными.